# Question about Dictionary<T,T>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class NumericalRange:IEquatable<NumericalRange>
    {
        public double LowerLimit;
        public double UpperLimit;

        public NumericalRange(double lower, double upper)
        {
            LowerLimit = lower;
            UpperLimit = upper;
        }

        public bool DoesLieInRange(double n)
        {
            if (LowerLimit <= n && n <= UpperLimit)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        #region IEquatable<NumericalRange> Members

        public bool Equals(NumericalRange other)
        {
            if (Double.IsNaN(this.LowerLimit)&& Double.IsNaN(other.LowerLimit))
            {
                if (Double.IsNaN(this.UpperLimit)  && Double.IsNaN(other.UpperLimit))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if (this.LowerLimit == other.LowerLimit && this.UpperLimit == other.UpperLimit)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

This class holds a neumerical range of values. This class should also be able to hold a default range, where both LowerLimit and UpperLimit are equal to Double.NaN.

Now this class goes into a Dictionary

The Dictionary works fine for 'non-NaN' numerical range values, but when the Key is   {NaN,NaN} NumericalRange Object, then the dictionary throws a KeyNotFoundException.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other interface that I have to implement?

Comment: Did you also override GetHashCode and Equals(obj)?

Comment: No. Are these overrides required? If so, how do you implement GetHashCode?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c/371348#371348

Comment: Also, you can simplify this code by initializing the range values to NaN and providing a parameterless constructor, thus not having to test that special case.

Comment: having an if to return a boolean value depending on how the condition evaluates can be simplyfied
E.g. 
if(A==b)
  return true

can be simplified to
return a==B;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on your comment, you haven't implemented GetHashCode. I'm amazed that the class works at all in a dictionary, unless you're always requesting the *identical* key that you put in. I would suggest an implementation of something like:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 17;
    hash = hash * 23 + UpperLimit.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 23 + LowerLimit.GetHashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

That *assumes* `Double.GetHashCode()` gives a consistent value for NaN. There are many values of NaN of course, and you *may* want to special case it to make sure they all give the same hash.

You should also override the `Equals` method inherited from `Object`:

```
public override bool Equals(Object other)
{
     return other != null && 
            other.GetType() == GetType() &&
            Equals((NumericalRange) other);
}
```

Note that the type check can be made more efficient by using `as` if you seal your class. Otherwise you'll get interesting asymmetries between `x.Equals(y)` and `y.Equals(x)` if someone derives another class from yours. Equality becomes tricky with inheritance.

You should *also* make your fields private, exposing them only as propertes. If this is going to be used as a key in a dictionary, I *strongly* recommend that you make them readonly, too. Changing the contents of a key when it's used in a dictionary is likely to lead to it being "unfindable" later.

Comment: Jon F&%$ing Skeet!! It's like asking for directions in the Vatican and being answered by the Pope!!!! http://preview.tinyurl.com/5va9gs

Comment: Stupid question, why 17 & 23?  Are those arbitrary numbers, or is there some rational to it?

Comment: I basically pick odd prime numbers. Apparently (according to Effective Java) 31 is a good multiplier as it corresponds to a shift and subtract, which modern optimisers will do for you. (EJ uses 17 and 31.)

Answer (score 7):

The default implementation of the GetHashCode method uses the reference of the object rather than the values in the object. You have to use the same instance of the object as you used to put the data in the dictionary for that to work.

An implementation of `GetHashCode` that works simply creates a code from the hash codes of it's data members:

```
public int GetHashCode() {
   return LowerLimit.GetHashCode() ^ UpperLimit.GetHashCode();
}
```

(This is the same implementation that the Point structure uses.)

Any implementation of the method that always returns the same hash code for any given parameter values works when used in a Dictionary. Just returning the same hash code for all values actually also works, but then the performance of the Dictionary gets bad (looking up a key becomes an O(n) operation instead of an O(1) operation. To give the best performance, the method should distribute the hash codes evenly within the range.

If your data is strongly biased, the above implementation might not give the best performance. If you for example have a lot of ranges where the lower and upper limits are the same, they will all get the hash code zero. In that case something like this might work better:

```
public int GetHashCode() {
   return (LowerLimit.GetHashCode() * 251) ^ UpperLimit.GetHashCode();
}
```

You should consider making the class immutable, i.e. make it's properties read-only and only setting them in the constructor. If you change the properties of an object while it's in a Dictionary, it's hash code will change and you will not be able to access the object any more.

Comment: I know how it feels to have answered correctly and hen overshadowed by the greatness of "The Skeet" +1 :)

Comment: @Guffa
I'm curious about your second code block.  With that implementation, if you have a lot of ranges where the upper and lower limits are the same, you will still get the same hash code, won't you?  It will just be non-zero.  Is there a benefit to having a non-zero, but highly duplicated hash code vs. highly duplicated values of zero?

Comment: @JMarsch: The reason that the first implementation gives the same hash code is because x ^ x always gives the same value regardless of the value of x, namely zero. (x * 251) ^ x gives different results for different values of x.